# Can't access Session from Generic Handler

Tags: .net, session

Got a classfile, helpers.cs, why does this code:

```
public class Helpers
{
    public static void LoginCheck(string Username, string Password)
    {        
        HttpContext.Current.Session["UserRoute"] = DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Give me the error:

> System.NullReferenceException

How can the Session be Null? Does my Helpers class need to inherit some other page or class?

The NullException is on this row:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserRoute"] = reader["Link"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler needs to implement the `IRequiresSessionState` marker interface.